# C operator += Sequence point?

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, sequence-points

Is this defined behaviour?

```
*p += *p--;
```

And, if it is, is it equivalent to `{ p[0] += p[0]; --p; }` or to `{ p[-1] = p[0]; --p; }` ?

I'm guessing the being defined or not depends on whether `+=` has an implicit sequence point and, if it has, my guess is that the second block should be the correct one.

EDIT: I think it's not a duplicate of the suggested question because the main question there is what are sequence points and how do the affect behaviour. In my case I have clear idea of what a sequence point is and the question is *specifically* on whether the `+=` operator has an implicit sequence point or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined behavior and sequence points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: I had not seen the question when I posted this one, but Lundin's answer is definitely more clarifying to me that the answers to the question you mention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is undefined behavior because the evaulation of `*p` is unsequenced in related to the evaluation of `*p--`. There is no sequence point. For all assignment operators, 6.5.16:

> The side effect of updating the stored value of the left operand is
>   sequenced after the value computations of the left and right operands.
>   The evaluations of the operands are unsequenced.

6.5 states that it is UB:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either
>   a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value
>   computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is
>   undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the
>   subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an
>   unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings.