# The following code giving answer 21. I am not understanding how the operators are working

Tags: operator-precedence, pre-increment

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i = 10;
  int d = ++i + i--;
  printf ("d = %d\n",d);
  return 0;
    }
```

This code printing d = 21. The order of evaluation is taken right to left and left to right, but still the answer is not evaluating to 21.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C operator += Sequence point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457904/c-operator-sequence-point)

Comment: It would be 22 if the `d = ++i + i--` assignment was divided into 2 lines of calculation.